# Error for System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel while debugging windows azure project in local environment

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, azure

I have recently updated from windows azure sdk 1.5 to 1.6. I was able to debug azure projects in my system with sdk 1.5. But after update i can no longer debug even newly created azure projects. Visual studio throws error "The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state. See output window for more information."

Following is the text from my output window:

Server Trace:

> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at System.IDisposable.Dispose()    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.FabricClient.AddServiceDeployment(String
>   tenantName, ServiceModelDefinition serviceModelDefinition, String
>   instanceDescriptionPath, ServiceDeploymentOptions options)

I am able to create package and the packages work properly on live deployment. 
I have already checked for web.config ready only. It is write able.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution:
Remove the "read only" property for the files present in the below path (on your development machine). This will fix the issue and enable you to run the application in debug mode.

`%LocalAppData%\dftmp\IISConfigurator1.6.0.0` folder

Note: IISConfigurator folder name may change based on Windows Azure SDK version you are working on.

**Edit :** You can  [find details from microsoft support engineer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sriharsha/archive/2012/04/07/system-servicemodel-communicationobjectfaultedexception.aspx)

Comment: This in the folder IISConfigurator2.7.0.0 along with a restart solved the same problem for me...